# How to merge 2 tile sets?

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles, gdal-python-binding

How to merge 2 overlapping tile sets into one tile set? What gdal utils can be used for that?

By tile set I mean folder with tiles produced by `gdal2tiles`

If it matters tiles are in .png format.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
gdal_merge.py image1.tif image2.tif -o merged.tif
```

where `image1` and `image2` are your input tiles and `merged` is your output. See also [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) for other options.

Comment: By tile set I mean folder with tiles produced by gdal2tiles, but your example about merging 2 *.tif images.

Answer (score 2):

**gdal_merge.py** is the python used to merge Rasters.

**Example:**

```
gdal_merge.py -o merged.tif input1.tif input2.tif
```

**Example Reference:**
https://github.com/dwtkns/gdal-cheat-sheet

**Main reference link:**
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html

Comment: By tile set I mean folder with tiles produced by gdal2tiles, but your example about merging 2 *.tif images.